Transfering MSF files in Thunderbird
My Thunderbird account is POP3
I backed it up, but there were issues with my PC Win 10
I could only find the MSF files in the backup.
I had to reinstall Thunderbird and now need to copy these MSF files into the new Thunderbird.
I found a programme called TOURG. it only helped me confirm that all the MSF folders are in tact.
It did't help in copying the MSF files.
Can you help

Do you have any other files from Mail/ besides the .msf files?

MSF = Mozilla Summary File - based on what I found these files are just an index file that do not contain the actual emails. A quick check on the MSF files I have locally also shows no mail content.

I'm really confused. As I said I used a programme called Tourg and it opened one of my MSF files. Is there anyway I can add an attachement to show more clearly what TOURG opened?
